# CSS3 transition or Javascript preloading effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm starting with CSS3 transitions and i've just found a nice effect on loading page like at this link : http://stsintegrity.com

I've been trying to make it by my own, by making an onload at the body, then a function with transitions in JS but its not working at all, and by CSS I cannot find a way.
So if someone can give me some directions to how work it arround or something similar to addapt it, I'll be very appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code that you used to implement the required transitions, so that we can follow on from there

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com We are volunteers who want to help you with a specific problem. We donate our time; donate some of yours and show that you at least tried something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with jQuery and [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/):

```
$(".transitionOverlayPage").transition({
    delay: 2000,
    y: '-120%'
}, 'slow', 'in', function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGAFF/Kk8rH/)

I added a 2 second delay so you can see it easier. (You would remove this) Basically, you would put that in your jQuery onLoad function.